# Oracle Apex saying can't update generated always identity column when trying to edit non ID column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table with 3 columns, Space_Status, Zone_ID and Parking_Space_ID, in the application builder I created an interactive grid report so that I can modify the status of each space, but when I try to change just the status I get the error ORA-32796, preventing me from saving the changes, despite the fact that I am not trying to modify the generated ID column.

[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you have made the column that is generated automatically, editable.

I doubt whether that will work. Please try the below options:

**Option 1:**
Change the column type to Hidden.
**Option 2:**
If the column must be visible then change column type to Display Only.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a sequence as a source for that column in Apex, it will be generating an insert statement with **null** for that column which would raise this exception.

If the database column is defined as **generated by default on null** it should work.